# How can I get files from multiple folders in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
public ActionResult DisplayFiles()
{
    var getCategory = dbcontext.tblDetails.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct().ToList();
    ViewBag.Category = getCategory;

    foreach (string category in getCategory)
    {
        ViewBag.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/" + category)).Select(fn => "~/" + category + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fn));
    }

    return View();
}
```

I tried to upload it like this where `category` returns the folder names from the database of table `tblDetails` from where I want to get the files.

Actually the above code overrides the folder name after every iteration of the loop and provides the last category name to the **Viewbag.Images** 
 and only display the files of that folder

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop to something like:
EDIT

```
List<string> images = new List<string>;
foreach (string category in getCategory)
{
    images.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/" + category))
               .Select(fn => "~/" + category + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fn)).ToList());
}
ViewBag.Images = images;
```

What you are doing in your loop is returning only the final image as the result will be over written on each iteration.

Comment: it is showing a compile-time error specifying **cannot convert 'System.Collections.Generic.JEnumerable<string>' to string**.

Comment: Sorry, it was missing a `ToList()`

Comment: I see to that but it is still not helpful

Comment: In what way is it not helpful? Do you have some sample data and the expected output in you web page. More detail would help.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually the above code overrides the folder name after every iteration of the loop and provides the last category name to the Viewbag.Images and only display the files of that folder

You could try to use `List<IEnumerable<string>>` to store all folders with their file names

```
var data = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();

foreach (string category in getCategory)
{
    var images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/" + category)).Select(fn => "~/" + category + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fn));
    data.Add(images);
}
ViewBag.Images = data;
```

Then in your view, you could display them as a group like

```
@foreach( var folder in ViewBag.Images)
{      
    <ul>
        @foreach (var image in folder)
        {
            <li>@image</li>
        }
    </ul>

 }
```